# Output user input to a file using variables

Tags: python, file, input

I am trying to take the user input for example the user input for `widgetName` and add it to the output that goes into a file between the `<title>` tags in the html.

I tried looking up how to do this but had no luck.

```
widgetName = input("Please enter the name you would like to use for your widget: ")

with open(os.path.join(widgetname, 'LockBackground.html'), 'w') as f:
    f.write("""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title> USER INPUT GOES HERE!! </title>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-UltraLigCond;
    src: url('fonts/font-file-goes-here');
}

# More CSS goes here.
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
# More javascript here.
</head>
<body>

# Code goes here.

</body>
</html> """)
```

Comment: I suggest googling _"python string formatting"_. There are several ways to do it. Or, even better, start with [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). It will teach you all the basics you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do 2 ways. one is to use `%s` string replacement, the other is using `{}`.

```
widgetName = input("Please enter the name you would like to use for your widget: ")

with open(os.path.join(widgetname, 'LockBackground.html'), 'w') as f:
    f.write("""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>{}</title>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-UltraLigCond;
    src: url('fonts/font-file-goes-here');
}

    # More CSS goes here.
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
# More javascript here.
</head>
<body>

# Code goes here.

</body>
</html> """.format(widgetName))
```

Another way

```
widgetName = input("Please enter the name you would like to use for your widget: ")

with open(os.path.join(widgetname, 'LockBackground.html'), 'w') as f:
    f.write("""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>%s</title>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-UltraLigCond;
    src: url('fonts/font-file-goes-here');
}

    # More CSS goes here.
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
# More javascript here.
</head>
<body>

# Code goes here.

</body>
</html> """ % widgetName)
```

Comment: Good answer. Python 3.6+ supports something called a formatted string literal (or "f-string") — see [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in the documentation, so there's a third way—and they might be even easier to use.